# INSERT ON DUPLICATE KEYs

Tags: mysql

How would I insert a row or update a row, if the matchid and videoset fields are equal to the current value?
This is what I have so far and I would expect if I ran this twice on an empty table, 3 rows of results should be the total amount returned. When I run this query twice, it does not update the 3 records added previously like expected, the query will simply add another 3 results. Any knowledge in this area would be highly appreciated. Thanks!

```
INSERT INTO videos (matchid, youtubecode, videoid, videoset) VALUES
(96, "Blahblahblah", '', '1'), 
(96, "WEEEEEE", '', '2'),
(96, "glgkgklbgjbgklbj", '', '3')
on duplicate key update matchid=values(videoset) AND videoset=values(videoset)


/*Column Information*/
----------------------

Field        Type          Collation          Null    Key     Default  Extra           Privileges                       Comment  
-----------  ------------  -----------------  ------  ------  -------  --------------  -------------------------------  ---------
matchid      int(10)       (NULL)             YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
youtubecode  varchar(300)  latin1_swedish_ci  NO              (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           
videoid      int(11)       (NULL)             NO      PRI     (NULL)   auto_increment  select,insert,update,references           
videoset     int(11)       (NULL)             YES     MUL     (NULL)                   select,insert,update,references           

/*Index Information*/
---------------------

Table   Non_unique  Key_name  Seq_in_index  Column_name  Collation  Cardinality  Sub_part  Packed  Null    Index_type  Comment  Index_comment  
------  ----------  --------  ------------  -----------  ---------  -----------  --------  ------  ------  ----------  -------  ---------------
videos           0  PRIMARY              1  videoid      A                    6    (NULL)  (NULL)          BTREE                               
videos           1  matchid              1  matchid      A                    2    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE                               
videos           1  videoset             1  videoset     A                    6    (NULL)  (NULL)  YES     BTREE
```

Comment: Do you have any constraints on the fields in your database?

Comment: Can you show us the table schema and primary key.

Comment: Edited with table schema and primary keys

Comment: Documentation states the index must be unique which I don't think is the case in my situation. Could this be the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You will have an error with your `INSERT` statement Justin. From your table's column information, you have said that:

`PRIMARY KEY` is `videoid` and is data  type of `INTEGER`.

But then, in your `INSERT` statement, you are inserting `''` in the `videoid` column.

```
INSERT INTO videos (matchid, youtubecode, videoid, videoset) VALUES 
(96, "Blahblahblah", '', '1'),  
                      ^ video id
(96, "WEEEEEE", '', '2'), 
                 ^ video id
(96, "glgkgklbgjbgklbj", '', '3')
                          ^ video id
ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE matchid = values(videoset) AND videoset = values(videoset)
```

Try changing `''` into a valid `INTEGER` value, for example `1`, the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE` will work.

Check my [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/802ed/1), the `SELECT * FROM videos` returned only 1 row as expected.

**EDIT 1**

I forgot that `videoid` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`. Check my updated [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/0bada/1).

Since that is the case, you do not need to include `videoid` in the `INSERT` statement.

```
INSERT INTO videos (matchid, youtubecode, videoset) VALUES
(96, "Blahblahblah", '1'), 
(96, "WEEEEEE", '2'),
(96, "glgkgklbgjbgklbj", '3')
on duplicate key update matchid=values(videoset) AND videoset=values(videoset);
```

But take note that all three records will be inserted in the table since `videoid` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, there would be no `DUPLICATE` records above.

**EDIT 2**

Since you have said that no rows should have the same `matchid` and `videoset`, the best way I can think of is using `COMPOSITE PRIMARY KEY`, just google it up. Unfortunately, I do not know if *SQL Fiddle* allows it. But here is an example:

```
CREATE TABLE videos (
    matchid INT(10),
    youtubecode VARCHAR(300),
    videoid INT(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
    videoset INT(11),
    PRIMARY KEY (matchid, videoset)
  );
```

or

```
ALTER TABLE videos ADD PRIMARY KEY(matchid, videoset);
```

in case that there is already a `PRIMARY KEY` defined, you just drop it

```
ALTER TABLE videos DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(matchid, videoset);
```

As you can see, I'm setting `matchid` and `videoset` as `PRIMARY KEY`. This way, when you are about to `INSERT` a record with `matchid` and `videoset` that is already existing, then it will do the statement after the `ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE`.

Comment: Thanks for the your suggestion KaeL :) The reason I leave the value blank for videoid is because it is an Auto Increment Key. If I was to place an INT inside, wouldn't it disrupt the auto increment process? is there no way to go about this without having to specify a videoid?

Comment: Check my answer again @JustinHarris

Comment: So it's not possible to check and see if (matchid AND videoset) are duplicates in the table and update them?

Comment: videoid is the only unique column. There is a unique combination however, which would be matchid and videoset. No two rows should have the same combination of matchid and videoset.

Comment: I see that the combination of `matchid` and `videoset` should be unique. Will edit my answer, wait for a moment.

Comment: Sorry but PHPMyAdmin is saying that multiple primary keys are not allowed.

Comment: You just have to delete the existing primary key. `ALTER TABLE videos DROP PRIMARY KEY, ADD PRIMARY KEY(matchid, videoset);`

Comment: I am getting an error that there can only be one auto-increment field and that it must be set as a primary key. In your latest response you are asking me to drop all keys and assign matchid and videoset as the primary keys... what should I do with my videoid auto increment?

Comment: I figured it out KaeL, I just needed to add the videoid as a unique key, and the matchid and videoset as primary. Thanks for all your help, you are a true gentlemen :)

Comment: Hi Justin, it would be my pleasure to help :D Thanks as well